# kivy how to display an image on a button with python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to display an image on a button using kivy but in python file.

```
self.add_widget(Button(source=('Image'),pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top":0.3},on_press="Screen"))
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image strings require their extension (so image.jpg or image.png depending)

You can add images to buttons through the use of the canvas OR you can assign their image using their [background](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html) methods:

For example, using background_normal:

```
self.add_widget(Button(background_normal=('Image.extension'),pos_hint={"x":0.3, "top":0.3},on_press="Screen"))
```

Which will set a picture for when the push isn't down or disabled.

Comment: Can I use online images with URL?

Comment: It would be more than likely possibly with sockets but that is far too much for this one thread. I'd recommend checking out ''Foundations of Network Programming in Python 3' (third edition) by Brandon Rhodes for more.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out the way to use images online. But thanks for helping me!